# Как устроена подсветка вопросов?

Tags: поддержка, faq, вопросы

Сколько не пытался анализировать, так и не понял:) 
Некоторые вопросы в списке по поиску подсвечиваются персиковым. (Полностью фон вопроса, голоса + заголовок + начало вопроса)

Так же интересно про подсветку "голосов за вопросы"(черный на белом; белый на темно-зеленом; золотой на темно-зеленом).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Почему бы и не рассказать.

---

**Серый ноль на белом** - вопрос без ответа
[image]

---

**Зеленый текст в зеленой рамке** - вопрос с ответом/ответами
[image]

---

**Белый текст на зеленом** - вопрос с принятым ответом
[image]

---

---

Любой из вариантов **с общим бежево-персиковым фоном** - вопрос содержит метку из числа ваших *избранных* меток, т.е. потенциально интересный именно вам.
[image]

---

Любой из вариантов **сильно обледненый** - вопрос содержит метку из числа ваших *игнорируемых* меток, т.е. потенциально неинтересный именно вам.
[image]

---

Любой из вариантов **с общим бледным бежево-персиковым фоном и бледным текстом** - вопрос содержит метку из числа ваших *избранных* меток и метку из числа *игнорируемых*, конфликтная ситуация.
[image]

---

При просмотре вопросов по конкретной метке она не участвует в сопоставлении с избранными/игнорируемыми. Т.е. для подсвечивания/обледнения в списки должна входить хотя бы еще одна метка, кроме текущей.