# Как работают избранные и игнорируемые метки?

Tags: поддержка, faq, избранные-метки

- Что означают *избранные метки* и *игнорируемые метки*? Как они работают?
- Что такое «*подписка на метки*»?

> Более подробно – см. «[Как найти интересные мне темы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics)» в [справочном центре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

См. также «[Как устроена подсветка вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2636/6)».

---

<sub>Перевод статьи «[What do “favorite tags” and “ignored tags” do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173/274323)».</sub>

Comment: таки дубликат частично ) http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2636/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2/2637#2637

Comment: @Nofate Спасибо! Добавил ссылку на публикацию в вопрос. Мне кажется, они дополняют друг друга более чем дублируют. Что скажите? Или все–таки закрываем один?

Comment: может объединить?

Comment: @Nofate Попробовал – не получилось. Не ясно, как вопрос соотносится с ответом, а если изменить вопрос, то как с ним соотносится другой ответ. То есть, чтобы объединить, надо и ответы и вопрос корректировать.

Answer (score 5):

*«Избранные метки»*: вопросы с этими метками (ранее известными как «интересные метки») выделяются в потоке вопросов особым цветом.

*«Игнорируемые метки»*: вопросы с такими метками отображаются с меньшей контрастностью: они видны, но менее заметны. Выставив флаг во флаговой кнопке «Скрыть игнорируемые метки», вы можете скрыть их совсем (необходимые действия выполняется на стороне клиента, поэтому возможны сторонние эффекты).

Данные предпочтения влияют на то, как отображаются вопросы на домашней странице («Последние вопросы») и других страницах сортировок вопросов.

Настройки доступны в боковой панели главной страницы сайта и на странице настроек учётной записи (также [вы можете использовать в поиске подстановочные знаки](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/), чтобы подсветить или исключить многочисленные связанные с запросом метки):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

См. также: [Формулировка ваших предпочтений относительно меток](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/expressing-your-tag-preferences/).