# Есть ли возможность отключить попадание в ленту вопросов, в категориях которых ты не разбираешься?

Tags: предложение, метки

Пару раз приходилось искать информацию на ru.SO, связанную с C#, Android Studio и Java. Вообще я в таких вопросах не разбираюсь, искал, как говорится, для расширения кругозора. Но теперь у меня в ленте постоянно появляются вопросы по этим меткам. Есть ли какой-нибудь способ указать, какие метки мне интересны и вопросы по каким меткам я хочу получать? Ну или хотя бы ограничить количество вопросов по меткам?

Если нет, то мой "вопрос" можно считать **предложением**. Предположим, что я разбираюсь в JavaScript, HTML и CSS. Пускай в мою ленту будет попадать 5 вопросов по меткам, в которых я разбираюсь, а потом один из совершенно другой отрасли. Мало ли, вдруг тема заинтересует? Преимущества такого подхода: не будут мазолить глаза и сбивать с толку вопросы, в которых ты не компетентен и будет больше вопросов, на которые ты сможешь дать ответ.

Сразу уточню про метки с малым количеством вопросов или про "подметки". Например CSS - глобальная метка. А CSS3 - "подметка", если можно так выразится, метки CSS. Так вот, если я указал, что неплохо разбираюсь в CSS, пускай вопросы из метки CSS3 тоже будут появляться в ленте.

Comment: [Вот этим](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3450/181100)?

Comment: @D-side а если я хочу игнорировать всё кроме `php` ?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский тогда смотрите не на главную, а только в метку [tag:php], очевидно.

Comment: @D-side ну это утрированно. Смысл был таков, что если я хочу следить за 1-2-3-4-5 метками, то заколебесси в игнор ставить остальные. Тем более могут быть оказаться связанные метки, как ТС говорит css-css3. А тыкать в каждую из интересующих меток тоже не вариант

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в этих случаях надо использовать скорее избранное, а не игнор. Сильно сомневаюсь в разумности "выкидывания всего остального". Я сам слежу где-то за десятком меток, но и вне них бывает что-то прикольное и известное мне.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно делать поиск по вопросам, имеющим ваши избранные метки.

1. Настройке список избранных меток: [Как работают избранные и игнорируемые метки?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3450/181472)
2. В поисковом запросе добавьте `intags:mine`. Можно [страницу с этим запросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=intags%3Amine) сделать закладкой и начинать просмотр новых вопросов с неё.

Вы также можете сделать запрос по произвольному набору меток. Примеры кликабельны:

- [`[java] [linux]`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+linux) — вопросы, имеющие все указанные метки
- [`[java] or [linux]`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+linux) — вопросы, имеющие хотя бы одну из указанных

> Пару раз приходилось искать информацию на ru.SO, связанную с C#, Android Studio и Java. Вообще я в таких вопросах не разбираюсь, искал, как говорится, для расширения кругозора. Но теперь у меня в ленте постоянно появляются вопросы по этим меткам.

Насколько я знаю, в Stack Exchange история прошлых запросов не влияет на выдачу. Вопросов про C#, Java и Android просто много.

> если я указал, что неплохо разбираюсь в CSS, пускай вопросы из метки CSS3 тоже будут появляться в ленте.

Когда-то обсуждали иерархические связи меток и пришли к выводу, что это довольно сложно поддерживать, так что будет больше проблем, чем пользы.

Answer (score 2):

Я для этого использую фильтры StackExchange и вижу только те вопросы, которые мне интересны. Правда с ruSO иногда какая-то задержка с обновлениями происходит. Вот [так](http://stackexchange.com/filters/217361/%D0%A0%D1%83%D0%A1%D0%9E) я вижу ruSO.

Comment: Отличный пример. )